# If Blightsteel Colossus loses its abilities through an effect like Lignify, can it be put into my graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I cast [Lignify](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lignify) on my opponent's [Blightsteel Colossus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blightsteel%20Colossus) and then deal 5 damage to it with one of my creatures, does it go to the graveyard since it has no abilities? Or is this ability regained once it is removed from the field since Lignify is destroyed at the same time?

Comment: The event Blightsteel Colossus normally replaces is "moving from anywhere to the graveyard" not "being in the graveyard."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The Colossus would be put into the graveyard because it doesn't have its "shuffle into its owner's library" ability when replacement effects would be checked.**

At the moment that your Lignified Colossus dies, it's still a 0/4 with no abilities.

From the comp rules for replacement effects:

> 614.4. Replacement effects must exist before the appropriate event occurs—they can’t “go back in    time” and change something that’s
> already happened. Spells or abilities that generate these effects
> are often cast or activated in response to whatever would produce the
> event and thus resolve before    that event would occur.
>
> *Example: A player can activate an ability to regenerate a creature in response to a spell
> that would destroy it. Once the spell resolves, though, it’s too late to regenerate the
> creature.*

It regains its shuffle ability once it hits your graveyard (since Lignify is gone). But the time for checking replacement effects has already passed. It stays in your graveyard.

Comment: Absolutely correct, nothing tricky about it. By the time it would regain its indestructible and shuffle into library abilities, it's too late.

Comment: But is it the creature that's indestructible? Or the card that's indestructible?

Comment: @corsiKa Indestructibility only applies to permanents -- I mean, how would you "destroy" a card in hand, for instance? "Blightsteel Colossus is indestructible" is a static ability that makes Blightsteel Colossus indestructible (indestructibility itself isn't an ability).

Comment: Blightsteel Colossus is both a creature and a card - the creature isn't in the graveyard, the card is. Consider Animate Dead which says "Return enchanted creature card..." even on its oracle text.