# Does Humility affect the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does [Humility](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Humility) effect cards in the graveyard? (EX. If Humility in play, can I discard [Blightsteel Colossus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blightsteel%20Colossus) without the shuffle?)

Comment: How do I add links again?

Comment: `[mtg:Card Name]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it only affects creatures, which is to say creature cards and tokens on the battlefield.

> 109.2. If a spell or ability uses a description of an object that includes a card type or subtype, but doesn’t include the word “card,” “spell,” “source,” or “scheme,” it means a permanent of that card type or subtype on the battlefield.
>
> 110.1. A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield. [...]

Comment: If Brightsteel is in play with Humility and dies, at what point does the card regain its ability? Would it go into the graveyard?

Comment: @Samthere [http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/6505/2474](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/6505/2474)